# Sum of length of the branches in a tree

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, a tree like this:

```
    5
   / \
  3   6
 / \
7   2
```

```
print(tree.branchLenSum())
```

will be `1+1+2+2=6`

Tree class:

```
class BinaryTree:

    # Constructor, takes in new key value
    def __init__(self, myKey):
        self.key = myKey
        self.leftChild = None
        self.rightChild = None

    # Returns root key value
    def getRootValue(self):
        return self.key

    # Changes root key value
    def setRootValue(self, newKey):
        self.key = newKey

    # Returns reference to left child
    def getLeftChild(self):
        value=None
        if self.leftChild!=None:
            value=self.leftChild
        return value

    # Returns reference to right child
    def getRightChild(self):
        value=None
        if self.rightChild!=None:
            value = self.rightChild
        return value

    def insertLeftChild(self, childKey):
        newNode = BinaryTree(childKey)
        newNode.leftChild = self.leftChild
        self.leftChild = newNode

    # Inserts key as right child. Existing right child becomes new right child
    # of new key
    def insertRightChild(self, childKey):
        newNode = BinaryTree(childKey)
        newNode.rightChild = self.rightChild
        self.rightChild = newNode
```

The tree I have built for the example:

```
tree=BinaryTree(5)
tree.insertLeftChild(3)
tree.insertRightChild(6)
nodeA=tree.getLeftChild()
nodeA.insertLeftChild(7)
nodeA.insertRightChild(2)
```

What I have so far:

```
def branchLenSum(self):
    rounds=0
    if self.getLeftChild() ==None and self.getRightChild()==None:
        return rounds+rounds+1
    else:
        rounds+=rounds+1
        if self.getLeftChild()!=None:
            rounds+=self.getLeftChild().branchLenSum()
        if self.getRightChild()!=None:
            rounds+=self.getRightChild().branchLenSum()
        return rounds
```

My idea is that every time travel to next node, counter adds 1+counter itself. I think this will get all the length sum.

Comment: That solution looks fine to me; what is your question? Is there anything not working?

Comment: The input I posted is not working well. I got output '5' from my program.

Comment: Can you somehow provide a minimal version of your tree class so we can test this? I would assume now, that the `getLeftChild` and `getRightChild` methods are not working correctly.

Comment: How do you *set* the children?

Comment: `rounds+=rounds+1` looks odd

Comment: Yes I changed again now.

Comment: Okay, one remaining question: Why do you expect the result to be 6? You are only counting the nodes of the tree, of which there are exactly 5.

Comment: @OneOfOne My idea was" new sum = old sum + oldsum + 1"

Comment: @poke - the correct answer is 6, it's just confusingly expressed. The OP appears to be asking for the total internal path length of a binary tree, for which there are formal definitions out there - basically, it's the sum of the depths of each node.

Comment: @poke I expect to get the sum of the lengh of branches.  I wrote a fuction to count the nodes before , I hope to get the branches sum function working by modifing the old one. I am think about get the sum of length of branches by sum=sum+sum+1 instead of sum=sum+1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so the reason why you only get a result of 5 is rather simple: What you are doing is *count* the nodes. So in your case, you have 5 nodes, so the result is 5.

If you want to get the internal path length, then I believe you will have to keep track of the current depth while navigating through the tree. You can do this simply by using an optional parameter.

```
def branchLenSum(self, depth = 0):
    rounds = depth
    if self.leftChild:
        rounds += self.leftChild.branchLenSum(depth + 1)
    if self.rightChild:
        rounds += self.rightChild.branchLenSum(depth + 1)
    return rounds
```

In this case, whenever we navigate down to a child, we increase the current depth by one. And when counting the branch length of a node, we start at the depth.

Btw. note that officially, the internal path length is defined as the length for only the internal nodes, i.e. not leaves. The method above counts every node including leaves. If you want to follow the official definiton, you will have to add a leaf-check at the beginning and return `0` for leaves.

---

Some other things:

- The methods `getLeftChild` and `getRightChild` do effectively nothing. You assign `None` to the return value, then check if the left/right child is `None` and if that’s not the case you assign the child to the return value and return it.

  So essentially, you are returning `self.leftChild`/`self.rightChild`; there’s no need to actually look at the value and check for `None`.
- In Python, you usually don’t use accessor or mutator methods (getters/setters); you just access the underlying property itself. This makes the methods `getLeftChild`, `getRightChild`, `getKey` and `setKey` redundant.
- Checking for `None` with `!= None` or `== None` is an antipattern. If you want to check if, for example a child is not `None`, just do `if child`. And if you want to check if it is not set (i.e. not `None`) just do `if not child`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I get it now. Just one more question, is there any ways that is able to accomplish this task without using any parameters other than 'self'?

Comment: This can be computed in constant time (without traversing the tree at all) if you always store at each vertex the total internal path length of its subtree and the number of vertices in its subtree. Then these two values can be updated in constant time every time you add a child.

Comment: You could probably do it without passing in the current depth if you returned a sequence of the relative depths of all children and added 1 to all of the elements of that sequence, then add a 0 for self, and eventually summed it. But that's really unclear compared to just passing in `depth`, I don't recommend it.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you could make it without using other parameters if you store the information elsewhere, for example in the return value. But this will require you to change the interface of the function too (having a more complex return value), or to have some internally used version of the function which is simply consumed by the real function. So you would have a lot more “mess” if you did it otherwise; the optional parameter (which you don’t need to specify) is really the best way to deal with it.

Comment: @SergeyOrshanskiy That’s true but that idea can be applied to a lot of things. It is certainly a possible optimization but it would also require quite a few other changes to maintain the correct value. Especially with more complex tree changes (e.g. rotations in binary search trees) this can easily get more complicated than necessary.